# Perl not running

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

I have experience with setting up multiple Perl program with mac before, but come to a strange situation today.

I delete one of my existing Perl folder and download it from GitHub, when I try to run again, it shows this error: [an error occurred while processing this directive].

So, what I do to debug is:

1) I create test.shtml (some problem displaying the arrow sign in here)

```
#exec cgi="/Users/lion/htdocs/app/cgi-bin/test.pl"-->
```

2) I create test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "content-type: text/html \n\n";
print "test";
```

3) I create a new htaccess

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
```

4) I set the test.pl permission to 777

5) I tested with http://app.local/test.shtml
    -> come out error [an error occurred while processing this directive].

6) If I manually run from console, it is working fine.

Here's my apache config as well.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/lion/htdocs/app"
    ServerName app.local
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/Users/lion/htdocs/app/cgi-bin/" 
</VirtualHost>
```

My apache error log show this:

```
[Wed Nov 09 16:45:25 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] invalid CGI ref "/Users/lion/htdocs/app/cgi-bin/test.pl" in /Users/lion/htdocs/app/test.shtml
```

Not sure what I missed out, my other Perl program is running just fine. Run out of ideas what cause the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exec cgi` [expects a URL-path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html#element.exec), not a file system path as an argument.

Try

```
#exec cgi="/cgi-bin/test.pl"
```

or just

```
#exec cgi="test.pl"
```

Comment: I run this without problem on another perl setup. I don't think this is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after spending sometime for debugging, found out the cause is a .htaccess with authentication in cgi-bin, it blocks the redirection.